# What is the difference between M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME

Tags: maven, development-environment

I have two version of environment variables for maven home - `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME`.

Which one needs to be set?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`MAVEN_HOME` is for Maven 1, `M2_HOME` is for Maven 2 and later.

Maven 2 was a complete rewrite from Maven 1 and was not backwards compatible.  Having the two different `_HOME` variables means it is possible to run both on the same machine.

**UPDATE**

As of maven 3.5.0 neither of these environment variables should be specified. Instead, the path should be updated to include the mvn executable.

Comment: And M2_HOME\bin should added to PATH as well for accessing it from any directory on command line :)

Comment: As of Maven 3 it is not necessary to use environement variables like `MAVEN_HOME` or `M2_HOME` anymore. The bin path of the Maven installation like `/usr/share/maven/` is just enough.

Comment: Why on the earth would they remove those environment variables ? Those environment variables made it possible to change Maven installation and the local repository directory. Now you can't mv the ~/.m2 directory to somewhere. They should work on making it XDG directory specification compliant.

Comment: To the previous commenter: within `~/.m2/settings.xml` you can configure a custom path to the local repository under tag `<settings><localRepository>`.

Answer (score 31):

And, ironically, you must still use M2_HOME and M2 for Maven version 3. Otherwise, it fails, because they didn't follow this logical approach with Maven V3.x for some bizarre reason.

Consequently, it is not easy to support Maven 2 & Maven 3 on the same machine without rewriting your configuration.

Comment: I just wanted to know the thought process behind this thoughtless action.