# maven not found on Yosemite

Tags: macos, bash, maven

I am trying to download Maven on my mac OSX yosemite.
I tried to download it manually and I wrote this in the .bash_profile

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

I also used the source command and I still get this error when I try to execute mvn command:

-bash: mvn: command not found

I tried to use an alternative solution to solve the problem, which is: brew install maven

But the problem is that brew is actually using an deadlink URL to download maven, thus, I was unable to solve the problem using brew!

In addition, I tried to search for JAVA_HOME but I couldn't locate it even though I have java 6,7, and 8 installed on my mac.

can someone please help me with this?

I tried to execute `sh mvn` and got this error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Have you tried MAVEN_HOME?

Comment: Why would I use MAVEN_HOME instead of M2_HOME?

Comment: You can try `MAVEN_HOME=$M2_HOME` ([backwards compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136324/what-is-the-difference-between-m2-home-and-maven-home))

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl By doing that I will be using MAVEN_HOME and $M2_HOME will just be a variable right? I want to use M2_HOME because I might need Maven 2 for any reason in the future and MAVEN_HOME is only for maven 1

Comment: Have you ran "`source .bashrc`" or on the `.bash_profile`

Comment: yes I did run it on .bash_profile

Comment: Why exactly did I get a down vote?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin"`

`mvn` executable is not in `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/` but rather in `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin` subfolder.

1. check that `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn` actually exists
2. check (e.g. with `ls -l`) that its permissions contain executable (`x`) flag. Use `chmod 0755 /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn` it they don't.
3. In any case `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn` is a shell script, so you may try to run it with shell directly: `sh /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn` and see if it runs indeed. If it still can't be run, use `sh -x /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn` to see exactly the line where it fails.

Comment: 1 and 2 look fine, however, I got an exception error after executing sh mvn, I will post the error in the question.

Comment: Ok, so you have at least two problems with your setup, one with `mvn` shell script and another with java classpath. Let's solve them one by one.

Comment: It does exist:  
`+ exec /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java -classpath '/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar' -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`

Comment: The problematic piece is `-classpath '/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar'` Likely the expansion isn't occured (in my installation it gets expanded to `-classpath /usr/local/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar`, notice the precise numbers there. Likely, your M2_HOME is set incorrectly. Unset it completely or at least set to `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5` not `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin`

Comment: I thought it's in bin because this is what I should have in my path? I tried to remove it from the path and re-executed sh -x mvn, however, I still get the same issue even though I now have  `-classpath '/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-*.jar'`

Comment: check that file `plexus-classworlds-<some-numbers>.jar` actually exists in `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5/boot` and is readable by you.

Comment: ops. It turns out that I wasn't installing it in the right path, I don't really know how did this thing happen because I was in /usr/local before (maybe I terminated the terminal and re-opened a new one and forgot about that). Anyway, I've moved the folders to /usr/local and I was able to execute mvn. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew has updated the Maven formula.

Use `brew update` and then try `brew install maven` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues but I got it resolved by adding `/bin` to `$PATH` as follows:

```
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```