# $ mvn -v – command not found

Tags: bash, maven, path

I installed Maven on macOS 10.12.6.
Added environment to `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PS1="\h --- \t *************************** \w $ "
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export MAVEN_HOME=/Users/{user}/Documents/Path/Maven/maven_3.3.9
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/{user}/Documents/Path/Gradle/gradle_6.1.1
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After that I save it and set `source .bash_profile` command in Terminal.
When I try in Terminal input `mvn -v` command I see:

> -bash: mvn: command not found

When I input `$MAVEN_HOME` I see:

> : No such file or directory/Path/Maven/maven_3.3.9

If I use `echo $MAVEN_HOME` command I see:

> /Users/{user}/Documents/Path/Maven/maven_3.3.9

If I input this `mvn` I see:

> -bash: mvn: command not found

JDK on Mac - `$JAVA_HOME` command in Terminal:

> -bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory

Can you help me please to understand where I missed.

Comment: Please don't use images to share textual information. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I would recommend to install the most recent version of Maven not an old version...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answers, I fixed my problem just like that:

`export PATH=/Users/{user}/Documents/Path/Maven/maven_3.3.9/bin:$PATH`

After that everything worked as expected.
If you think my method is not good, please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a maven 2+, export `M2_HOME` (see "[What is the difference between `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17137183/6309)")

And double check what echo `$PATH` returns after sourcing the `.bashrc`.
Make sure it:

- includes `$M2_HOME/bin`
- `ls $M2_HOME/bin` does exists.

Comment: See also https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-set-java_home-maven_home-environment-variable-in-macos/

Answer (score 0):

**Check this**

1) Review your path, I think you are missing '$' character right before {user}

2) Review execution permission for 'maven_3.3.9/bin/mvn'

3) Make sure you are using Bash as Unix shell (and not zsh or another)

```
echo $SHELL
# output should look like: '/bin/bash'
```

4) If you are using bash then add maven's ENV variables to the file ~/.bashrc (or ~/.zshrc if you are using zsh)

5) 'source' your configuration

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Notes**

- I recommend understand differences between *.bashrc* and *.bash_profile*: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html
- If you want to keep your configuration on *.bash_profile* then just rebooting your system should be enough (to start a login shell which load *.bash_profile*)